# ServiceStack client from example

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servicestack

I try client example from - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client

```
    public class Hello
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:52849/hello");

        HelloResponse response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
    }
```

But on the last string:

```
HelloResponse response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
```

get eror:

```
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for                 'ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Get(ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturnVoid)' has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Maksim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DapperTest\DapperTest\Program.cs  32  38  DapperTest
```

I try Alternative API:

```
var response = client.Get<HelloResponse>("/hello/World!");
```

its work without errors, but string:

```
response.Result.Print();
```

get exceptions:

```
Error   4   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Print' and no extension method 'Print' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Maksim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DapperTest\DapperTest\Program.cs  34  29  DapperTest
```

Comment: Might sound dumb but did you install the NuGet package `ServiceStack.Common` in your client project?

Comment: PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Common 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'ServiceStack.Text (≥ 3.0 && < 4.0)'.
'ServiceStack.Common 3.9.70' already installed.
DapperTest already has a reference to 'ServiceStack.Common 3.9.70'.

Comment: Hmm... it just looks like some reference is missing.

Comment: var response = client.Get<HelloResponse>("/hello/World!"); - good work. I cast "response" variable to "HelloResponse" and work with him.